# Copy row if cell value more than 0 - Google Sheets

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have some cells in a spreadsheet that I am trying to use to do some price calculations for some different services. Each row has:

- The name of each service
- The quantity of the service that is being requested
- The price per unit of the service
- Finally, the total price which is calculated by multiplying the unit price by the quantity

However, I have done this for 10-15 services and as such not all the services will be used every time. So now I would like to try and create a summarised version which would explain exactly the same information as above but only for the chosen options. To work out which services to show, I planned on filtering to show only if the calculated price is more than 0

I have seen that there is the `FILTER` function and so I tried to do the following:

```
=FILTER(F6:F9, F6:F9 > 0)
```

This does do the basic job of only showing the values that are more than 0. However, is there a way that I can extend this to also copy over information from the columns beside it? Or would I have to use another function or a script to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need to do is extend `FILTER` range like:

```
=FILTER(F6:H9, F6:F9 > 0)
```

it could even be like:

```
=FILTER(A6:B9, F6:F9 > 0)
```

but you can use `QUERY` if you prefer like:

```
=QUERY(A6:Z9, "select F,G,H where F > 0", 0)
```